# Javascript + sign is concatenates instead of giving sum of variables

Tags: javascript

if x,y,z are all 1 its giving the answer 111 rather than 3

```
    x=prompt ("Enter first Number"); 
y=prompt ("Enter second Number");
z=prompt ("Enter third Number"); 
p= x + y + z ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```js
x = parseInt(prompt("Enter first Number"), 10);
y = parseInt(prompt("Enter second Number"), 10);
z = parseInt(prompt("Enter third Number"), 10);
p = x + y + z;
console.log(p)
```

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.